# remove a specified number of characters from a string in C

Tags: c, string

I can't write a workable code for a function that deletes N characters from the string S, starting from position P. How you guys would you write such a function?

```
void remove_substring(char *s, int p, int n) {

    int i;

    if(n == 0) {
        printf("%s", s);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < p - 1; i++) {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }

    for (i = strlen(s) - n; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }


}
```

Example:

```
s: "abcdefghi"
p: 4
n: 3
```

output:

```
abcghi
```

But for a case like n = 0 and p = 1 it's not working!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please include your attempt before asking.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Aha! I thought that you code looks like `int main() { s: "abcdefghi"; p: 4; n: 3; }`

Comment: if (n==0) ... else ... do the rest

Answer (score 4):

A few people have shown you how to do this, but most of their solutions are highly condensed, use standard library functions or simply don't explain what's going on. Here's a version that includes not only some very basic error checking but some explanation of what's happening:

```
void remove_substr(char *s, size_t p, size_t n)
{
  // p is 1-indexed for some reason... adjust it.
  p--;

  // ensure that we're not being asked to access
  // memory past the current end of the string.
  // Note that if p is already past the end of
  // string then p + n will, necessarily, also be
  // past the end of the string so this one check
  // is sufficient.
  if(p + n >= strlen(s))
    return;

  // Offset n to account for the data we will be
  // skipping.  
  n += p;

  // We copy one character at a time until we 
  // find the end-of-string character
  while(s[n] != 0)
    s[p++] = s[n++];

  // And make sure our string is properly terminated.  
  s[p] = 0;
}
```

One caveat to watch out for: please don't call this function like this:

```
remove_substr("abcdefghi", 4, 3);
```

Or like this:

```
char *s = "abcdefghi";

remove_substr(s, 4, 3);
```

Doing so will result in undefined behavior, as string literals are read-only and modifying them is not allowed by the standard.

Comment: I would add `if (!p || !n || !s) return;` in the beginning. Really bad things can happen if any of them is `0` for some reason.

Comment: @NikBougalis Thanks. Your solution is understandable :)

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, you didn't implement a removal of a substring: your code prints the original string with a range of characters removed.

Another thing to note is that according to your example, the index `p` is one-based, not zero-based like it is in C. Otherwise the output for `"abcdefghi", 4, 3` would have been `"abcdhi"`, not `"abcghi"`.

With this in mind, let's make some changes. First, your math is a little off: the last loop should look like this:

```
for (i = p+n-1; i < strlen(s); i++) {
    printf("%c", s[i]);
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/52VA4y)

If you would like to use C's zero-based indexing scheme, change your loops as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    printf("%c", s[i]);
}
for (i = p+n; i < strlen(s); i++) {
    printf("%c", s[i]);
}
```

In addition, you should return from the `if` at the top, or add an `else`:

```
if(n == 0) {
    printf("%s", s);
    return;
}
```

or

```
if(n == 0) {
    printf("%s", s);
} else {
    // The rest of your code here
    ...
}
```

or remove the `if` altogether: it's only an optimization, your code is going to work fine without it, too.

Currently, you code would print the original string twice when `n` is `0`.

If you would like to make your code remove the substring and return a result, you need to allocate the result, and replace printing with copying, like this:

```
char *remove_substring(char *s, int p, int n) {
    // You need to do some checking before calling malloc
    if (n == 0) return s;
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    if (n < 0 || p < 0 || p+n > len) return NULL;
    size_t rlen = len-n+1;
    char *res = malloc(rlen);
    if (res == NULL) return NULL;
    char *pt = res;
    // Now let's use the two familiar loops,
    // except printf("%c"...) will be replaced with *p++ = ...
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        *pt++ = s[i];
    }
    for (int i = p+n; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        *pt++ = s[i];
    }
    *pt='\0';
    return res;
}
```

Note that this new version of your code returns dynamically allocated memory, which needs to be `free`d after use.

Here is a [demo of this modified version on ideone](http://ideone.com/Qubpup).

Comment: @NaVi It does - check out the demo at the link.

Comment: yes it works, excuse me... you said that 'strictly speaking' I haven't done a substring removal... but how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try copying the first part of the string, then the second

```
char result[10];
const char input[] = "abcdefg";

int n = 3;
int p = 4;

strncpy(result, input, p);
strncpy(result+p, input+p+n, length(input)-p-n);

printf("%s", result);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to do this without the use of functions like `strcpy` or `strncpy` (which I see you said in a comment) then use a similar approach to how `strcpy` (or at least one possible variant) works under the hood:

```
void strnewcpy(char *dest, char *origin, int n, int p) {
    while(p-- && *dest++ = *origin++)
        ;
    origin += n;
    while(*dest++ = *origin++)
        ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What did you try?  Doesn't `strcpy(s+p, s+p+n)` work?

Edit:  Fixed to not rely on undefined behaviour in `strcpy`:

```
void remove_substring(char *s, int p, int n)
{
    p--; // 1 indexed - why?
    memmove(s+p, s+p+n, strlen(s) - n);
}
```

If your heart's really set on it, you can also replace the `memmove` call with a loop:

```
char *dst = s + p;
char *src = s + p + n;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s) - n; i++)
    *dst++ = *src++;
```

And if you do that, you can strip out the `strlen` call, too:

```
while ((*dst++ = *src++) != '\0);
```

But I'm not sure I recommend compressing it that much.

Comment: A quick check of the man page says `strcpy` with overlapping strings causes undefined behaviour.  I'll fix it momentarily.

Comment: it works for strcpy(s + p - 1, s + p + n - 1). But i want to know how to do without a procedure like strcpy, if you understand what i mean :)

Comment: Why is `p` 1-indexed?

Comment: You could compress it more to `while (*dst++ = *src++) ;`, but then it would be too much like my second answer :P

Comment: Certainly, yes.  Clang and GCC both complain about the assignment in the conditional without a second set of parentheses, though, and I don't like the look of `((*dst++ = *src++))`, so I went with the explicit `!=`.  Decisions decisions decisions....

Comment: At least the decisions are there. I mean, its a little different, but look at the string .equals() mess in java.

Comment: One small, nitpicking point: this version does no error checking and will happily read past the end of the string if the `p` and `n` arguments are incorrect.

Comment: Also true; I personally subscribe to the standard-library-style of error handling when it comes to utility functions like this one.  That is - no meaningful error handling at all.  More decisions!  There's no way to handle all possible errors anyway; bad pointers, un-terminated strings, etc.  Production code (or a more complicated routine) are of course different situations entirely.

Comment: @CarlNorum what means 1-indexed? I think you decremented p because the  position to start is 0 not 1, right?

Comment: Yes; you're counting `p` as if the first character in the string is number 1, which is a bit weird.

Answer (score 1):

metacode:

- allocate a buffer for the destination
- decalre a pointer s to your source string
- advance the pointer "p-1" positions in your source string and copy them on the fly to destination
- advance "n" positions
- copy rest to destination

Comment: Theoretically I thought about this but I don't know how to implement, I'm learning C, this is why I want to see others solutions...

Comment: You won't really learn by copy&pasting. But you sure will by looking up different keywords mentioned in this answer. If only more people would answer like this...